# ¿ Cómo pasar de mi Splash Screen a Activity con BottomBar?

Tags: android

Quiero poner una pantalla de presentación que dure 3 segundos y después muestre mi proyecto. La pantalla de presentación con un icono al medio funciona, y dura lo que tiene que durar pero a la hora de iniciar `MainActivity1` la aplicación se me detiene.

> 11-01 13:59:56.770 27073-27073/? E/dalvikvm: could not disable core file generation for pid 27073: Operation not permitted
>   11-01 13:59:56.790 27073-27080/? E/jdwp: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe

**El problema que hay creo que es que `MainActivity1` usa un `BottomBar` por lo que hay conflicto entre `MainActivity` y el `BottomBar`**

Aquí está el código que muestra la foto 3 segundos:

`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {`

```
protected static final int TIMER_RUNTIME=3300;

protected boolean mbActive;
protected ProgressBar mProgressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_presentacion);

    //  mProgressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity1.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            MainActivity.this.finish();
        }
    }, 3300);

    final Thread timerThread = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mbActive = true;
            try {
                int waited = 0;
                while (mbActive && (waited < TIMER_RUNTIME)) {
                    sleep(200);
                    if (mbActive) {
                        waited += 200;
                        updateProgress(waited);
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            } finally {

                onContinue();
            }
        }
    };timerThread.start();

}

public void updateProgress(final int timePassed){
    if(null != mProgressBar) {

        final int progress = mProgressBar.getMax() * timePassed / TIMER_RUNTIME;
        mProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
    }
}

public void onContinue(){
    Log.d("mensagemFinal","subarra");
}
}
```

**MainActivity1** :

`public class MainActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {`

```
BottomBar mBottomBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
        getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    }

    mBottomBar = BottomBar.attach(this, savedInstanceState);
    mBottomBar.setItemsFromMenu(R.menu.menu_main, new OnMenuTabSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMenuItemSelected(@IdRes int i) {


            if (i == R.id.one) {

                First_fragment f1 = new First_fragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, f1).commit();

            }

            if (i == R.id.two) {

                Second_fragment f2 = new Second_fragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, f2).commit();

            }

            if (i == R.id.three) {

                Three_fragment f3 = new Three_fragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, f3).commit();

            }

            if (i == R.id.four) {

                Four_fragment f4 = new Four_fragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, f4).commit();

            }

            if (i == R.id.five) {
                Five_fragment f5 = new Five_fragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, f5).commit();

            }


        }


    });

    mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(0, "#c92029");
    mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(1, "#c92029");
    mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(2, "#c92029");
    mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(3, "#c92029");
    mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(4, "#c92029");

   // seems this is  working to highlist tab
    mBottomBar.selectTabAtPosition(0, true);


    // Loading first Fragment to FrameLayout manually
    First_fragment f1 = new First_fragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, f1).commit();


}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    // Necessary to restore the BottomBar's state, otherwise we would
    // lose the current tab on orientation change.
    mBottomBar.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar **`TimerTask()`**, te voy a colocar lo que yo hice hace un tiempo, es exactamente lo que quieres, es decir, un `SplashScreen`, lo que hace es después de unos segundos me manda a la segunda actividad, es decir, `MainActivity`, te coloco todo para que lo comprendas y le entiendas:

```
package mx.appco.RevistaPremisa;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.TextView;


import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView titulo_revista, frase_revista;


private static final long SPLASH_SCREEN_DURACION = 3700;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
    Typeface fontTitle =Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Angeline_Vintage_Demo.ttf");
    Typeface fontSubtitle = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "champagne.ttf");
    titulo_revista = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_revista);
    frase_revista = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.subtitle_frase);
    titulo_revista.setTypeface(fontTitle);
    frase_revista.setTypeface(fontSubtitle);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

   //Aquí empieza lo importante
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {


            Intent mainIntent = new Intent().setClass(
                    SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(mainIntent);
            //
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.fade_out);


            finish();
        }
    };


    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(task, SPLASH_SCREEN_DURACION);
}
}
```

Comment: Pero eso especial para bottombar o algo ? Lo de splash screen yo lo tengo implementado en otras aplicaciones , lo que me ocurre que en este no me deja.

Comment: se me detiene la app

Comment: No hagas caso,mi unico problema era que no lo habia declarado en el Manifest..... En fin... gracias.

Comment: -.- Sugiero que la próxima vez revises bien si es un error de programación o error humano, me la pensaré en ayudar .-.

Comment: Aquí se ponen las cosas ya revisadas pero como humano me puedo equivocar y no declararlo en el manifest, que no te sepa mal, te agradezco la respuesta y te puse como +1.